# Unexpected output from nested functions

Tags: function, nested, closures

I'm working through the [Mozilla tutorial on JavaScript, "Nested functions and closures"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

I have this function:

```
function outside(x){
    function inside(y){
        return x + y;
    }
    return inside;
}
```

This should return 8:

```
fn_inside = outside(3);
result = fn_inside(5);
result1 = outside(3)(5);
console.log(result);
```

But it returns 10 – why is that?

Comment: No way, you need to attach video to prove that :p

Comment: Well I tried it again and it worked this time. I don't know... Maybe because I but a lot of tasks and logs in one script, and then I comment the old ones out... Sorry and thanks for your time. I'll be more careful!